# Sequential files search c++

Tags: c++, file, sequential

i am working on hangman game , the player must guess a word. 
i have created a file that include words , and it is the reference for my game. 
my game generate a random number and then search file for a word. 
for example my file consist of 100 words and when game generate the number for example 10 , it must go to the tenth number word.
i want to create a file with notepad , and read from it.there is one easy way to search :just search one by one till you reach the generated number. but i want a more quick way. i want to write data in same length in a file ,so i can search it for only one time , to know how much word exist in it , then i can create a random file with it.and when my game generate a number use seekg() and go to that spot.

so question is this: can i do this with a file typed by myself? 
and if i cant so i need to write a code like this in the program:

```
ofstream outputfile("outfile.dat", ios::binary);

char word[10];

while (cin >> word)
{
    word[9] = '\0';
    outputfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&word),
        sizeof(word));
}
```

in my reference there was something like this for objects. but here it doesn't work, and when i want to read from this file i only get a blank line. 
this code can be in formatted way but it doesn't work too!and it doesn't output word in same length.

i use this peice of code to read from the file but it doesn't work:

```
ifstream in("outfile.dat", ios::in |ios::binary);
while(in.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&word), sizeof(word)))
    cout << word << endl;
```

what is problem? this method work for objects ...

and the second question : do you think an algorithm like this is good at all??

thank you so much

Comment: Since files (even text files) are really just long sequences of bytes, it's difficult to jump around to specific lines. However, it would be sufficiently efficient to simply read the entire file once at startup into a vector of words, then choose items from the vector instead of re-reading from the file.

Comment: Not immediately relevant, but you can still overflow the buffer. Use a std::string instead. Read your file into a std::set<std::string>

Comment: Read the file into a `std::vector<std::string>` at the beginning and then use the vector to find words to use.

Comment: it is a good idea , but why i can't read from the file?? i have attached file successfully to an ifstream file , and read it with inputfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&word),sizeof(word)) , why it doesn't work? this way works for objects ...

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&word)` <- what

Comment: when you read from the file ,const char * is not valid

Comment: What you are probably looking for [tellg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg). Note this tells you the current read position so this is the position for the next word you are about to read.

Comment: doesn't make any difference seekg is 0 , so it must read first word , but it doesnt